# Join two tables in SQL and return result set which includes null values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have voting sites where each site is a row in the table. Now on my web server, I need to load all sites, and check for each site if its been voted (Voted means the site id exists in the other tables's row).

So if the site id = 5 and row with `site_id` 5 exists in `callback_votes`, then the query will add that id to `'voted'`, if not it will be null.

**example:**

```
SELECT sites.*, callback_votes.site_id AS voted
FROM sites 
INNER JOIN callback_votes ON callback_votes.site_id = sites.id;
```

This query works, however, if I will not have any rows in `callback_votes`, the query will return no data. What I want to do, I want to still return `sites.*`, just for `voted` to be null in that case.

Is that possible or are there other ways for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Join on two tables where on column is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314323/sql-join-on-two-tables-where-on-column-is-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `INNER JOIN` which will return rows where there is a matching row in each table, what you need is a `LEFT JOIN`.

Using `LEFT JOIN` in simplistic terms means "select all rows from the left table, where there are no matching rows in the right table then return null".

Here's how your query may look:

```
SELECT sites.*, callback_votes.site_id AS voted
FROM sites 
LEFT JOIN callback_votes ON callback_votes.site_id = sites.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use left join insted of inner to adquire all data from sites and null values if not in callback_votes

```
SELECT sites.*, callback_votes.site_id AS voted
    FROM sites 
    LEFT JOIN callback_votes ON callback_votes.site_id = sites.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with LEFT JOIN

SELECT sites.*, callback_votes.site_id AS voted,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(callback_votes.site_id,'') = '' THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END IS_SITE_VOTED
FROM sites LEFT JOIN callback_votes ON callback_votes.site_id = sites.id;

CASE  is for the SQL-Server you can use IF for MYSQL.