# SQL Checking if exists in other table, if not then check it's type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query which checks if I have voted on other sites, by callbacks, [you can read more about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956159/join-two-tables-in-sql-and-return-result-set-which-includes-null-values)

```
SELECT sites.*, callback_votes.site_id AS voted
FROM sites
LEFT JOIN callback_votes
ON callback_votes.site_id = sites.id
AND callback_votes.ip = '127.0.0.1'
ORDER BY sites.id DESC
```

But now I came to a dilemma, where I need to set voted as `site_id` if it's type equals to 'none'.

So the query will see if `site.type` equals to 'none', then set `site.id` as voted, else see if there are ids on the table callback_votes and set voted as `site_id`, like it does now in the query.

How can I do that? If I will use a WHERE statement, it will only show results with `sites.type = 'none'` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a `case` statement?

```
SELECT s.*, 
       (case when s.type = 'none' then s.id else cb.site_id end) as voted
FROM sites s LEFT JOIN
     callback_votes cb
     ON cb.site_id = s.id AND cb.ip = '127.0.0.1'
ORDER BY s.id DESC;
```

I find the description of the logic a bit hard to follow because `cb.site_id = s.id`.  The only question is when the value will be `NULL` or `s.id`.

If you want to ignore votes in this case, then you can include the condition in the `on` clause as well:

```
SELECT s.*, 
       (case when s.type = 'none' then s.id else cb.site_id end) as voted
FROM sites s LEFT JOIN
     callback_votes cb
     ON cb.site_id = s.id AND cb.ip = '127.0.0.1' AND s.type <> 'none'
ORDER BY s.id DESC;
```

Note that putting conditions on the first table in an `on` clause has a peculiar effect.  When there is no match, the row is still included in the output, just without any matching columns from the other table.